# table td cell exceeded and over to next line on pdf, excel put this on new row cell while converting pdf to excel using aspose.pdf

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, aspose.pdf

While converting pdf file to excel using aspose.pdf, if content of a td cell exceeded and moves into new line then on excel it goes to new row cell rather then to keep it on same cell, this should be on same cell. Here's example in picture:
PDF Picture:
[image: PDF Picture]

Excel Picture:
[image]

here you can see on excel it goes to another row cell. this should be on same cell as you can see on pdf. I am using aspose.pdf for conversion.

Comment: Just post process your excel by merging the cells that are in a row with an empty A cell. I doubt Aspose can be tricked to doing the right thing for you.

Comment: Could you please try using 21.5 version of Aspose.PDF for .NET as we have improved PDF to Excel Conversion Engine in the latest version. In case issue still persists, please share your sample PDF document by uploading it to Google Drive or Dropbox so that we can test and address the case accordingly. You can also create a post and share your file securely over the official Aspose.PDF Support forum (https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf/10) which is the right place to discuss such issues. This is Asad Ali and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.